What to do if new hinge clamp has no gap (brompton)
I just installed new hinge clamps on my Brompton, but there's no gap. What should I do?
It's been just under 3 years since I last replaced the hinge clamps on my 2015 Brompton M6R. I noticed that there was no longer a gap on between the hinge clamps and the frame, so I replaced them.
Unfortunately, I found that there is still no gap between the hinge clamp and the frame.









After replacing the hinge clamp, there is a reasonably large gap between the handlebar support hinge and the hinge clamp
After replacing the hinge clamp, there is nearly no gap at all between the mainframe hinge and its support clamp














Hinge Outer Left
Hinge Outer Right
Inside Open 1
Hinge Open 2



According to the Brompton Data Sheet ds-hcpl, this is bad.








The Brompton Data Sheet ds-hcpl warns that there should be a 0.90 mm gap between the hinge and hinge clamp




If the gap between the hinge and the hinge clamp plate is less than 0.90 mm (fig. 2) replace the hinge clamp plate. The bike should not be ridden if there is no gap between the hinge clamp plate and the hinge, until the plate is replaced...
In the extremely rare case of a new hinge clamp plate not resolving the issue, please contact your local Brompton dealer...

There is exactly 0 Brompton dealers in the country I'm living.
What are the risks to riding a Brompton where there is no gap between the hinge and the hinge clamp? And what is the remedy for it?

Was the replacement plate a brompton part of an aftermarket/knockoff part?  And was it new?  I'm wondering if the mating surface on the frame is worn down ?  Is it still painted ?

The hinge clamps were brand-new OEM purchased from an authorized brompton dealer (shipped internationally at quite an expense). I assume the mating surface has worn down, and I don't know what the fix is for that.

ask the Brompton dealer for the suggested repair.  Though I'm astonished the steel has worn that far.  If it were me and I was back-yard bodging it, I'd get some thin strips of Turkite and build up the mating faces on the bike.  Its an engineered plastic that is super hard, and you stick it on with 2 part epoxy.  Turkite is used for building up worn ways in machines like lathes and mills, and can be scraped "flat" for alignment.   But ask Brompton first.

The picture gives me the impression to still have some gap, but maybe not enough (try to see with a light pointing towards you at the other side of the hinge).
My understanding of the gap is simply that if there’s really no gap, the clamp will be blocked by the outer edge of the hinge instead of the ‘sloped’ part of the frame/hinge. So in a more extreme scenario, you’ll have a gap on the sloped part of the interface, and you’ll have some play at the hinge.
But the best is to contact directly Brompton by mail, only them can give an authoritative answer. But I doubt it will deviate much from the tech note: if they have defined the threshold at 0.9mm, no reason that they deviate from that.

Yeah to the naked eye I coudln't see a gap, but in the HD photo above you can just barely see a tiny bit of daylight through the hinge clamp. I have no idea how to measure it, but I suspect it's less than 0.90 mm, and it probably won't be long (a few months?) before the aluminum hinge clamps wear and there's no more gap.
